# Optimize quadratic form weighted Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $\alpha\in [0,1]^K: \sum_{i=1}^K\alpha_i=1$, and assume we have $K$ vectors $\{x(1),...,x(K)\}$ such that $x(i)\in\mathbb{R}^d, \forall i \in [K]$.

Consider the Gram matrix $G(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i x_i x_i^T$.

Now consider the optimisation problem for $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$

$$\sup_{\alpha\in[0,1]^K: \sum_{i=1}^K\alpha_i=1} y^\top G(\alpha)y. $$

Does this problem admit a unique solution, many solutions, no solutions?

I think it should have a unique solution since we have the maximum of $G(\alpha)$ that is a polynomial function of $\alpha$ over a compact set, but I am not sure about it.

How is it possible to solve it?

Comment: What exactly is $A$?

Comment: It's $G(\alpha)$, it was a typo. The question is now updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Delta \subset \Bbb R^K$ denote the simplex of dimension $K-1$. This problem can be more simply rewritten as
$$
\sup_{\alpha \in \Delta} \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i(y^Tx_i)^2.
$$
It is easy to see that this maximum is attained with $\alpha_j = 1$ and $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i \neq j$, where $j = \operatorname{argmax}_i (y^Tx_i)^2$. This is the unique point at which the maximum is obtained if and only if $j$ is the unique maximizing index.

Comment: sorry I missed the fact that $\alpha$ belongs to the simplex of dimension K, Now I updated the question

Comment: @t See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks @Ben! Do you think your solution still holds if $G(\alpha) =( \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i x_i x_i^T)^{-1}$?

Comment: @temporary_freak No, it does not

Comment: How does it change? The original problem was actually with the inverse.

Comment: @temporary_freak I don't know how to find an expression for the supremum in the case that there's an inverse

Comment: I have figured that out. Thanks Anyway @Ben.